# Is there a way to make ASP.NET MVC 3 OutputCache vary by deep properties?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, caching

I'm testing the ASP.NET MVC 3 `OutputCache` attribute and the behavior is as follows:

- If you don't specify a VaryByParam attribute, it will automatically vary by all parameters
- If you specify, it will vary just by those separated by comma like "param1,param2"

But if your Action has a complex parameter, let's say, a Person, I can't make it to vary by a property of Person. Let's say.. Person.Name

I can't make it to work neighter by saying nothing or explicitly specifying model.Name

Is there a way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either hack the API a bit by sending `Person.Name` as an additional parameter (just for the sake of caching), or you can use [`VaryByCustom`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.varybycustom.aspx) attribute option and provide your own resolver. In the second case, you need to edit your `Global.asax` and override the `GetVaryByCustomString` method:

```
public override string GetVaryByCustomString(HttpContext context, string custom)
{
    if(custom == "Person")
    {
        // extract Person.Name here and return it
    }
    return String.Empty;
}
```

Then add `VaryByCustom="Person"` to your attribute declaration.

Comment: I was looking for a more straightforward solution. In this case I'd prefer to arrange the Actions in such a way that the core cache parameters would be scalar. Thank you anyway :)